# Use Gradle's DependencySet in depencencies block or other way to use multiple modules from one group

Tags: gradle

Gradle has an interface called [`DependencySet`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencySet.html) that Spring's [`dependency-management-plugin`](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) can use in a `dependencies` block in a `dependencyManagement` block like below. (Code from [here](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/blob/v1.0.0.RC2/README.md#dependency-management-dsl) for reference.)

```
dependencyManagement {
     dependencies {
          dependencySet(group:'org.slf4j', version: '1.7.7') {
               entry 'slf4j-api'
               entry 'slf4j-simple'
          }
     }
}
```

This is a very pretty to group dependencies that are in the same group. The more dependencies in the group the prettier it gets. Projects tend to have a lot of dependencies from the same group, especially if you are using Spring. Is there any way to use a similar notation in the "real" dependencies block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there isn't a way how to use `dependencySet` outside of the `dependencyManagement` section added by the Spring `dependency-management-plugin`  plugin.

You can take a look at the following classes to see how the dependencies are being read from the script:

- [DefaultProject](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/fe9e9cc8a03d4b03937f00d2321aee4b1ca04f1c/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProject.java) - method `dependencies()`
- [DefaultDependencyHandler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/ecc85ec6bb37378db10bcf099a0fc8b7e0242243/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DefaultDependencyHandler.java)

The interface for `dependencySet` is used differently in Gradle. For example it is returned when you want to know [all dependencies from a configuration](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/fe9e9cc8a03d4b03937f00d2321aee4b1ca04f1c/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.java).